# what is the best way to parse out the text after the last instance of a character

Tags: c#, string

I have the following string:

```
string test = /test/test1/tse3/ttese3/test3-45-NameToParseOut
```

and i need to parse out the word "NameToParseOut".  I basically need to find the last "-" and return all of the text after the last instance of "-".  What is the most elegant way of parsing this out in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string test = "/test/test1/tse3/ttese3/test3-45-NameToParseOut";
test = test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf('-')+1);
```

This works even for strings that do not contain dashes (in these cases the entire string is returned).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string test = "/test/test1/tse3/ttese3/test3-45-NameToParseOut"; 
int index = test.LastIndexOf('-');
string value;
if(index != -1) {
    value = test.Substring(index) + 1;
}
```

Read more on LastIndexOf(char) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904293%28v=VS.71%29.aspx